# ICC library search options

Tags: gcc, static-libraries, intel, icc

GNU compilers use `-llib` options to link with libs, is there something similar in `icpc`?

(I already have specified the -L option to add my lib in the search path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`icpc`, or any other compiler as far as I know, uses the same option to link libraries, so just use `-llib` with `icpc` as well

Comment: I'm not using `icpc` anymore, but here goes a counterexample: the -lopenmp and -openmp

Comment: -openmp is not for linking, it's for enabling OpenMP support (which is a lot more than just linking)

I'm aware that GCC uses -fopenmp, but what compiler is using -lopenmp?